# Convergence of a series by root test

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following series:

$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left ( \frac{2k+1}{3k+1} \right )^k
$$

and I must study its convergence. I use the root test. Then $\sqrt[k]{\left ( \frac{2k+1}{3k+1} \right )^k}= \frac{2k+1}{3k+1}$, whose limit is $\frac{2}{3}$. Is my argument correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the root test, but you showed the convergence right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's fine and strightforward by root test, as an alternative since

$$\left ( \frac{2k+1}{3k+1} \right )^k\le \left ( \frac34 \right )^k$$

the given series converges by direct comparison test with geometric series.